# C# equivalent of VB.Net AddressOf Operator

Tags: c#, vb.net

Code:

```
public Thread ThreadReceive;

ThreadReceive = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ReceiveMessages)
        ThreadReceive.Start()


    Public Sub ReceiveMessages()
        Try
            Dim receiveBytes As [Byte]() = receivingUdpClient.Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint)
            txtIP.Text = RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString
            Dim BitDet As BitArray
            BitDet = New BitArray(receiveBytes)
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Can anyone Please Suggest me How to convert this line:

```
ThreadReceive = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ReceiveMessages)
```

vb to C#

Thanks,
Basha.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming no name changes, this should work:

```
ThreadReceive = new System.Threading.Thread(receiveMessage);
```

`AddressOf` creates a delegate to `ReceiveMessages` and this is implied in C#.

Comment: It shows follwing error  Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart)' has some invalid arguments E:\Doing Projects\ttesting1\ttesting1\Form1.cs 71 33 ttesting1
Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Threading.ThreadStart' E:\Doing Projects\ttesting1\ttesting1\Form1.cs 71 61 ttesting1

Comment: What is the signature of `ReceiveMessages`?

Comment: ... and what version of .Net are you using?

Comment: public void receiveMessage()
        {
            try
            {
                Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingudpclient.Receive(ref remoteipendpoint);
                               

                

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }

        }

Comment: visual Studio2008 .Net3.5

Comment: Case matters -- `ReceiveMessages` is not the same as `receiveMessages`.

Comment: @user3075085:  I missed that you had renamed it to `receiveMessage` and not `receiveMessages`.

Comment: @user3075085:  No problem.  I know VS 2012 with ReSharper would've highlighted the naming issue for you.  ReSharper with VS 2008 would probably do it as well.

Comment: Iam developing application receving udp data through Ethernet plz suggest me how to do it

Comment: @user3075085:  That's not how things work here.  Try and ask questions when you cannot figure things out.

Answer (score 1):

```
ThreadReceive = new System.Threading.Thread(ReceiveMessages);
```

where `ReceiveMessages` is a method of type `void`.